# iOS: Hide border when scrolling pages in PageViewController

Tags: ios, border, uipageviewcontroller

How to make page overlaps a border of PageViewController view?

I setup view boarder like this:

```
self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
```

[image: PageViewController]

Comment: So you are asking to hide the border only on some parts where the page interescts the border right?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to hide the border:

```
self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

or

```
 self.view.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

I hope you are using this method to turn the pages with animation:

```
 - (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers 
                 direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated 
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;`
```

Try to hide the border when the animation starts and restore the border when the animation completes.

Comment: I want to hide borders only under my page, when I'm scrolling.